# How to pass an argument to errors.rejectValue() which is another property of a ResourceBundle in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to pass the ResourceBundle's (globalmessage.properties) property name "**atm.number**" instead of the hard-coded text "Número de cajero" as an argument of the "**errors.required**" property. How would I do that in a Validator?

**ReporteIncidenciaValidator (Validator):**

```
public class ReporteIncidenciaValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ReporteIncidencia.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ReporteIncidencia reporteIncidencia = (ReporteIncidencia) target;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(reporteIncidencia.getNumeroCajero())) {
            errors.rejectValue("numeroCajero", "errors.required",
                new Object[]{"Número de cajero"}, "");
        }

    }
}
```

**globalmessage.properties:**

```
errors.required={0} es requerido.
atm.number=Número de cajero
```

**servlet-context.xml:**

...

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:globalmessages" />
</beans:bean>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is using the ApplicationContext class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>locale\messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>

public class ReporteIncidenciaValidator implements Validator, ApplicationContextAware  {
    private ApplicationContext ctx;


    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ReporteIncidencia.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        String message = context.getMessage("yourKey", 
                new Object[] { }, Locale.US);
        // your code

    }
}
```

Comment: @alfredo-osorio You can use the rejectValue (org.springframework.validation.Errors)  
`errors.rejectValue(field, errorCode, new Object[]{"args"}, defaultMessage);`